# How do I change this code to be functional programming in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and as I'm reading this book. It basically says that if you code contains "var" it means that you're still doing in a imperative way. I'm not sure how do I change my code to be functional way. Please suggests.

So basically what this code does is to processText some text and use regular expression to extract a particular text from "taggedText" and add that to a list and convert the list to json.

```
    val text = params("text")
    val pattern = """(\w+)/ORGANIZATION""".r

    var list = List[String]()
    val taggedText = processText(text)
    pattern.findAllIn(taggedText).matchData foreach {
      m => list ::= m.group(1)
    }

    pretty(render(list)) // render to json
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing the middle section with

```
val list = pattern.findAllIn(taggedText).matchData.map(m => m.group(1)).toList
```

You can write `m => m.group(1)` as `_.group(1)` if you want.

Comment: As a more general rule, building up a data structure functionally Scala usually turns out to be best done using either "map", "flatMap" or "fold", in increasing order of difficulty.  There are a few variants on those ("collect", "groupBy", "foldMap") that may be handy in certain cases, but as a general rule "map", "flatMap" and "fold" get you where you need to go.

Comment: If those methods are new to you I recommand yield. You can use a for comprehension and yield the result collection. Behind the scenes yield is translated to map, flatmap, filter and so on.